# install gcc 4.7 on openbsd, but still 4.2 after installation

Tags: gcc, openbsd

I install gcc 4.7 on openbsd using pkg_add. after installation, I use 'gcc -v' to check, I found it is also gcc 4.2 !

how to upgrade gcc 4.2 to gcc 4.7 on openbsd? thank you!

Comment: have you tried with the config file that openbsd must have, so you point to the new gcc installation and not the old one?

Comment: would you please explain 'config file' exactly? Thank you!

Comment: The GCC 4.7 is installed as egcc. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I believe it gets installed as `eg++` and `egcc` in `/usr/local/bin/`.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the compiler on a BSD is a big thing. The assumption is you may need to use the compiler to recompile the system on an update. As such, I'm sure you don't update /usr/bin/gcc on a pkgadd. It could leave you with a system that can not be updated.

The compiler is most likely installed in a different directory. Even a simple rename wouldn't help, since gcc is not just gcc, but a whole slew of libraries, headers, and other utilities. You would need to find the directory where the new gcc binary is installed, then prefix that to your PATH.

I would use the [pkg_info](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg_info&sektion=1) tool to query where the package was actually installed into. Then I would find the directory where the binaries are, and set PATH=/path/to/new/gcc/bin:$PATH in the appropriate shell startup files.

Answer (score 0):

I get confused at first, but know I could give you a little help since I don't have OpenBSD installed, I thought it was a program not an OS, anyway...

as I see and reading the manual...(Have you read it?)... the correct way to do this would be:

`pkg_add -u gcc` in order to upgrade... not make a new installation, you could uninstall gcc and try to make a clean installation running `pkg_delete gcc`, but before you do something, try searching if it's true you have the two versions of gcc running `pkg_info` it should show you all the packages installed...

[Here](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html) is the link to the manual for packets and ports and all I can tell you is read the manual... regards..